# React/Redux/Firebase createStore Config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

When I try to `npm start` my project I don't see any error on the terminal. I am new to **react-redux-firebase**. Here is the error that I can see using my browser:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Screenshot:
[image]

Here is the code of `index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import firebaseConfig from "./config/fbConfig";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reactReduxFirebase(firebaseConfig),
    reduxFirestore(firebaseConfig)
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I am not sure what is wrong I just followed the tutorial on **YouTube**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that **YouTube** tutorial is out of date. I could reproduce your issue and I guess it is happening because of `reactReduxFirebase(firebaseConfig)` line in your code within `compose`.

In the official documentation - which states there are [breaking changes](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html#breaking-changes) - which contains that they removed `reactReduxFirebase`, please read as follows:

> Removed from API: `reactReduxFirebase` store enhancer (firebase instance is now created by context providers)

In **VSCode** the **IntelliSense** shows that `reactReduxFirebase` is a namespace now and not a function:
[image: namespace-not-a-function]

So as the migration guide mentioned maybe you can try to remove that line and replace that store enhancer with `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider`.

For more information please read and follow the [Change Snippets](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html#change-snippets) part of the documentation. It's pretty detailed with step by step examples.

I hope this helps!